# Is this login code right, because it doesn’t seem to work

Tags: php, session, redirect, isset

```
<?php

    include_once '../../includes/dbconnect.php';

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: ../../-/ucp/index2.php');
    }

?>
```

It doesn't redirect me to that page `index2.php` when I am logged in & when username is stored in the session. The session has already started—via `session_start()` in the file `dbconnect.php` that is included at the beginning of the script.

What went wrong?

Comment: I would wager that headers (read ANYTHING) are already sent before you try to use the `header()` function. If you have sent anything to the user, this will stop the redirect working.

Comment: the folder is named as `/-/` ? Show more codes. Recommend to debug the contents of `$_SESSION`.

Comment: You need to include `session_start()` at the top

Comment: OP said the session has already been started in included file.

Comment: @Fluffeh if i use !isset and i set that header link into the else, it still doesnt works, but !isset does work, on the same page.

Comment: @MarkM I really thought i already started the session in the included file(s), ive only shown one.. But i didn't. I admit my stupidity.

Comment: use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` before your path

Comment: `header('location : ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/your_project/-/ucp/index2.php')`

Comment: @Raptor Do you like my map name?

Comment: I don't care how do you name your path. What is the content of `$_SESSION`?

Comment: @AldiUnanto
header('Location: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . /myproject/-/ucp/index2.php');
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes no sense:

```
header('Location: ../../-/ucp/index2.php');
```

Maybe you should change that to full URL like this:

```
header('Location: http://your.great.site/-/ucp/index2.php');
```

The reason `../../-/ucp/index2.php` makes no sense is that the browser would interpret that `../../` as whatever URL you are on should drop down to the path two levels up… But are you 100% sure there is a place 2 levels up? Full URLs are the way to go.

Also there is a larger issue in your code where you are relying on relative paths which is not good practice. It can trip you up—like it clearly is here—and the best way to avoid it is to set a base path in your main config.

So you would set something like this in a config file:

```
$BASE_PATH = '/full/path/to/your/codebase/here/';
```

If you don’t know what your file system base path is, just place this line of code in your PHP code; like `index.php`:

```
echo "Your path is: " . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "<br />";
```

Then load that page. Somewhere near the top will be this text:

```
Your path is: /full/path/to/your/codebase/here/
```

Then with that set you can change your code to be something like this:

```
<?php

    include_once '../../includes/config.php';
    include_once $BASE_PATH . 'includes/dbconnect.php';

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: ../../-/ucp/index2.php');
    }

?>
```

Yes, it seems like more work to setup a `config.php` that is loaded via a relative path and then using `$BASE_PATH` on the next line, but the benefit is that once those `/includes/config.php` lines are set, you no longer have to worry about it.  Then `$BASE_PATH` can be set to meet the needs of whatever setup you are on.

That said, how about setting a `$BASE_URL` as well? Something like this:

```
$BASE_URL = 'http://your.great.site/';
```

So then you can do this in you code:

```
<?php

    include_once '../../includes/config.php';
    include_once $BASE_PATH . 'includes/dbconnect.php';

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $BASE_URL . 'ucp/index2.php');
    }

?>
```

That way your base settings are all in one place, you can just code without being derailed by relative path or URL nonsense, and get on with life!

Comment: I am using the header in multiple maps / files. It does work with upping 2 folder paths. But it does makes sense, lets try it. Thanks